# Error reading data from the connection

Tags: c#, firebird

We have written several C# web services that have a connection to our internal Firebird 2.5.5 database.

Unfortunately the exception "Error reading data from the connection" is thrown more and more often and we don't know how to fix it.

We tried to disable pooling but this did not have the desired effect.

We also wrote a try catch block that reconnects and re-executes the SQL, but this does not seem to us to be the right solution.

Is there another option?

Here are some environment informations:

- C# 7.0
- .NET 4.5
- Firebird Version 2.5.5
- Firebird Driver 5.5.0
- The Firebird log does not show any error messages at that time
- The error happens from time to time with any sql statement

Comment: Try catching `FbException` specifically and check the `ErrorCode` property. This might at least give some more information about the cause of the problem (see http://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfrefdocs/Firebird-2.1-ErrorCodes.pdf) - or you could just reconnect only when it's 335544726.

Comment: Stacktrace:
 ...

        {
          "Message": null,
          "ErrorCode": 335544726,
          "StrParam": "",
          "Type": 1,
          "IsArgument": false,
          "IsWarning": false
        },
        {
          "Message": "Error reading data from the connection.",
          "ErrorCode": 335544726,
          "StrParam": "",
          "Type": 0,
          "IsArgument": false,
          "IsWarning": false
        }
      ],
      "errorCode": 335544726
    }

Comment: You could then "improve" the hack by only reconnecting then `ErrorCode == 335544726`. I can't find the original bug report on the firebird pages but I remember it had the "won't fix" status years ago.

Comment: OK thank you but what should i do with Transactions?

Comment: Found it: http://firebird.1100200.n4.nabble.com/Error-reading-data-from-the-connection-td4638893.html

Comment: I'll post my experiences as an answer, these comment boxes are too small :(

Comment: Please **edit** your question with more information, don't provide additional information in the comments. And please, post more information, like the full exception stacktrace, the full Firebird version, the full Firebird ADO.net provider version and sample code the produces the error.

Comment: Also check the logs and event log on the machine hosting Firebird to check if the process isn't crashing (and automatically restarting).

Comment: I'd suggest that you start by updating both Firebird and the Firebird .net provider (eg to 2.5.8 and 5.12.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is relatively simple: the network connection between client and server is interrupted or broken for some reason, but the `State` of the client connection remains `Open` - even though you cannot use that connection anymore. Unfortunately Firebird decided to not update this status to `Broken` automatically, which would make a lot more sense if you ask me.

You already figured out that reopening the connection "somewhat fixes" the problem, and we have discussed that you could do this only when `FbException.ErrorCode` is 335544726.

Unfortunately this does mean that any open transaction is also lost, and you cannot commit any data from it anymore. The only way I could think of to reliably recover from this situation is to rethrow the exception:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (FbException ex)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == 335544726)
    {
        // close the connection (reopen depending on your application)
    }

    throw;
}
```

This way, you can catch this exception at a higher level in your application, and deal with it however is appropriate at that point - ie. retrying the entire transaction, or letting the user choose what to do.

Comment: If this occurs more and more often, then I would be highly suspicious of the reliability of the network between the web server and the database, or if the Firebird process is crashing regularly.